# debugger is not getting attached in xaml on app startup

Tags: c#, wpf

I have VS2010 installed and open the WPF Application. I had kept a break point at the start of the application. The project is running under debug mode. But the debugger point is not hitting. if I make any changes to the code, that is reflecting but breakpoint is not hitting.

I tried the following things:

1. Re-install Visual Studio
2. Tried all things in the below links.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7078b8/breakpoints-are-not-working-in-visual-studio/

Can any of please help me to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Did you try newer VS? Either Debug symbols are wrong or to modern. Are the dots in full red or white when app is running?

Comment: Where di you put the breakpoint?